# Pre-processing Video Frame before calling Vision API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, google-vision

In NodeJS,
I need to run some Vision API call on a live video stream.

What pre-processing to do to select the best frame before calling the API ?

- Compare frame N with N-1 ? How ?
- Detect motion blur ?
- What frame rate should I use ? 1 fps ?

I didn't find best practice to extract frames from video for SaaS Computer Vision processing. It seems to be a common use case ? Video are too large to upload.

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer your question, you might look at the team's sample app (in C#) for suggestions: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-VideoFrameAnalysis

Comment: I don't understand, it seems the code pick frames and send them async to microsoft cognitive services but there is no local analysis ?

Comment: The Cognitive Services APIs all run in the cloud.  The repo was intended to show how you might use the image-based APIs instead of the full-blown video-based ones.